# Showing that $\sum_{k\mathop=n}^{\infty} \frac 1 {k^2} < \frac 2 {2n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

I need to show that

$$\sum_{k\mathop=n}^{\infty} \frac 1 {k^2} < \frac 2 {2n-1}$$

Could I have a small hint?

I have tried many things, like bounding it above with the corresponding integral but this is too weak. I have tried subtracting $1$ from each of the denominators (excluding the first term) and then evaluating the resulting telescoping sum, but even that turns out to be too weak.

Comment: you tried a proof by induction?

Comment: @yanko ah, never thought of that for some reason!

Comment: Induction doesn't seem to work either...

Comment: Is it the $n=1$ case or the induction step that doesn't work?

Comment: @yanko The induction step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac1{k^2}<\frac1{k^2-\frac14}=\frac1{k-\frac12}-\frac1{k+\frac12},$$ so
$$\sum^\infty_{k=n}\frac1{k^2}<\sum^\infty_{k=n}\left(\frac1{k-\frac12}-\frac1{k+\frac12}\right)=\frac1{n-\frac12}=\frac2{2n-1}$$

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Compare with the integral of $1/x^2$, by comparison with the integral, you obtain that $\sum_{k\geq n}{1\over k^2}<\int_{n-{1\over 2}}^{+\infty}{1\over x^2}dx={2\over{2n-1}}$.

Comment: I have tried that. It is not enough

Comment: @TsemoAristide Well it is actually $\frac 1 {n^2} + \frac 1 n$.